# Android Studio: git repository with multiples modules

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I want to create a **git** (bitbucket) repository from my local Android project under **Android Studio**. This project contains an **external module** (addThisSDK).

When trying to create a repository (VCS => Import to version control => Create git repository ), a ".git" folder is generated under the main module (Mykintore), but **nothing for the external module**.

**So my question is : is it possible to generate a git repository for a whole project (with all modules source included) ?**

[image: git]

Thank you

Comment: you can try `git add --all` command and push it

Comment: thank you for your reply. ```git add``` will add all files under the "mykintore" folder, and "addThisSDK" will be ignored.

Comment: thats what you hv to use `--all` in root folder of ur project, then everything will be added

Comment: Is adding addThisSDK in gradle build not a solution?

Comment: How did you include your external module? Cloned a repository? Just downloaded source files?

Comment: Modules were automatically generated from an eclipse project as external module.

Comment: @johann some files must not be added. check your gitignore file, there's some config files that must be generated by android studio and they are different from an envirement to another !!!